# AttributeError: module 'posts.views' has no attribute 'add_comment_to_post'

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, python-django-storages

i am new to python and while adding comment option to my djang project while editing the views.py its show while typing

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

the terminal shows the following:

> File
>   "/home/user/Documents/DJANGO-COURSE-2.xx/DJANGO_COURSE_2.xx/21-Social_Clone_Project/simplesocial/posts/urls.py",
>   line 12 , in 
>       path('post//comment/', views.add_comment_to_post, name='add_comment_to_post'), AttributeError: module 'posts.views' has
>   no attribute 'add_comment_to_post'

and the views.py and urls.py file:

[image: image description is of view.py file]

[image: image description of urls]

Comment: Please don't add pictures of your code, copy the actual code and format it with the code format button (=indent with 4 spaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is an incorrect indentation of your function.

`add_comment_to_post` is currently part of the previous defined class (with has the function `delete` for example).

So if you change your indentation the error will be gone, e.g.

```py
class MyView(...):
    ...
    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        messages.success(self.request, 'Post Deleted')
        return super().delete(*args, **kwargs)


# next method should not have the same indentation of `delete`
def add_comment_to_post(request, pk):
    ....
```

Comment: i have edited my question and this is the error which i come up after it it would be so helpful if you could help me with this too

Comment: @FathimaAzeez Please do not edit a post to ask a different question. If an answer helped you, mark it as accepted and ask the new question with a new post. One post is only meant for one question each.

Comment: ok sir i didnt knew about that as iam new to coding and all thank you for your valuable advice i not repeat the same isssue again

Comment: @FathimaAzeez also please consider [marking the answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) since it helped you in the first place.